# Поиск массива данных в таблице

Tags: php, sql

Есть один user, у него в таблице хранится массив ID любимых товаров.
Необходимо сделать запрос в таблицу товаров, а затем сделать последовательный вывод названий и ссылок на картинки.

Пробовал вариант

```
arr = array(5,6); //5 и 6 id товаров 
$arr_lists = '\'' . implode ( "','", $arr ) . '\'';
$query2 = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT * FROM `product` WHERE `id` IN (" .$arr_lists . ")");
$result2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
echo var_dump($result2);
```

Но на выходе почему-то получаю дамп только первого товара.
Как через цикл вывести все найденные значения?

Comment: Цикл добавьте как в примерах http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 0):

цикл помог

```
 while ($result2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)) {
 echo $result2['name'];
 echo '<br>';
echo $result2['url'];
echo '<br>';
}
```